# Visual Studio Publish WebApplication is slow updating unchanged files

Tags: asp.net, azure, visual-studio, compilation, publish

Im doing publish with other coworker. When I and going to publish on azure after he did a publish, it does really slowly. It gets visual studio stuck(Skipping files and the Updating files that werent changed or touched) for somewhat 7minutes.

Our site is a WebApplication WebForms running on .Net Framework 4.8. Files output after compile are: assets, the main DLL+other references dlls and folders with the aspx files (no aspx.cs).

It seems that if he publishes 2 times in a row after my publish, the second one goes fast, but the first takes ages.
It happens in both our machines.

We do have image/xml/js files that are published as well, yet nobody edits them.
Build Action: Content
Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy
Generally the ones being re-published together with other dll references..(too much megabytes...)

I suspect that when I publish it compiles and change some timestamp of unchanged files in output folder.. but Im not sure.

One solution that we thought it would be to get a machine with Jenkins(Automation Platform) to detect git changes, build there and upload there..

We stopped building on Azure Instance(Git deploy) to get faster build times, but now it takes ages to publish..

How can we publish our code to production without getting stuck and avoiding publish of unchanged files?

Answer (score 1):

> I suspect that when I publish it compiles and change some timestamp of unchanged files in output folder.

- Visual Studio tries to publish only the changed files, but sometimes it might not work as expected. Once clean the solution and build it and check that only necessary files are included in the output.

Here, I have created a sample WebForms application with image/xml/js files as you have mensioned.

[image]

- This leads to more efficient incremental publishing. You can also specify options to optimize the deployment. Here I choose github deployment.

[image]

- Setting up a continuous integration system (like Jenkins) is good but also can try GitHub Action deployment pipeline.

[image]

*Deployment:*

[image]

[image]

- Use Azure Deployment Slots to deploy your application to a staging slot first and then swapping it with the production slot. This way, you minimize downtime during deployments.